# How I get child threads wait on a condition and all waked up by one call from parent thread?

Tags: c

Child threads sleeps to wait condition, and the parent thread can call some routine to wake up all child threads to run?

Comment: What threading API are you using?

Comment: mhm - could you possibly provide a little more detail about what you are working on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using POSIX threads (pthreads), then [`pthread_cond_wait`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_cond_wait.html) and (in your case) [`pthread_cond_broadcast`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_cond_broadcast.html) are your friends. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Win32, then you can use a manual-reset [Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686915(VS.85).aspx). Your parent thread would call [`SetEvent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686211(VS.85).aspx) and could wake up all child threads waiting for that object with a function such as [`WaitForSingleObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032.aspx).